# How can I make terminal screen blank and only show what I type? (without prompt)

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm unsure how to make my terminal screen blank. I need some to use some typing on it for a creative project I'm doing but it always contains the computer's info. No need to communicate with anything or anyone on it, I just want the look that it's blank.

Similar to this:

[image: example]

I'm using macOS.

Comment: If it's Windows, use the command `cls`. If it's Linux, use `clear` or `reset`.

Comment: It's macOS, I'm using the Cathode app (discontinued)

Comment: It's macOS and I used the CMD+K to clear it and the line that says "My-iMac..." is still there.

Comment: Why does this question resemble [this other question here on the Movies and TV Stack Exchange site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/118364/18230)? The only difference seems to be there are just different users posting each item? Same user accidentally created a new account?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux you can simply set the terminals prompt blank by running `PS1=""`.

To clear the current terminals output, use the `clear` command.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was a bit of a combination. First I entered `PS1=""` then followed that with a <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Thank you all for your help! Don't have enough rep to post the photo of it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What does Cmd-K do?

Comment: It clears the page. It doesn't remove the original command prompt though. Use the answer Kamil provided to do that. CMD+K will leave it blank afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this in a shell:

   ```
   clear; cat >/dev/null
   ```
2. Type freely.
3. Exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> ([twice, if needed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701317/108618)).

Comment: This is actually the best comment. The other way I could not paste information into the window, your way I can! You are fantastic and have saved me hours of headache. God bless you man!